# Creating a type using interfaces in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have the following `value` type in a map that I have:

`Function<? extends GenericContainer<?>, ? extends GenericContainer<?>>>`

I was hoping to assign `? extends GenericContainer<?>` in such a way that I can reference this function like so:

`Function<CustomType, CustomType>`

Is it possible to achieve this with a simple interface or abstract class?

#### Example:

```
  private interface ContainerType extends <? extends GenericContainer<?>> {}
```

or

```
  private interface ContainerType<T> {}

  class ContainerType implements ContainerType<? extends GenericContainer<?>> {}
```

Comment: your question might have some substance here, but you need to edit it to make it more clear. For example `private interface ContainerType extends <? extends GenericContainer<?>> {}` will not even compile.. also what is `CustomType`?

Comment: @Eugene I know it won't compile, I'm just trying to show my thought process. I'm not completely sure how to code it up in a way that is sensible. Almost like an alias for a longer type.

Comment: I guess you are trying to substitute `? extends GenericContainer<?>` with something easier and "smaller"?

Answer (score 0):

This is a blind flight because I do not know where you wanna go with this, but here's some options that work and might bring you closer to what you need:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class NolymorphismLol {

    static abstract class GenericContainer<T> {
        abstract T getContent();
    }

    Function<? extends GenericContainer<?>, ? extends GenericContainer<?>> basicFunction;



    static class MyReplacementClass extends GenericContainer<String> {
        private String myItem;
        @Override String getContent() {
            return myItem;
        }
    }
    static class MyReplacementClass2 implements Function<MyReplacementClass, MyReplacementClass> {
        @Override public MyReplacementClass apply(final MyReplacementClass pT) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    interface MyReplacementInterface extends Function<MyReplacementClass, MyReplacementClass> { /* */ }

    Function<MyReplacementClass, MyReplacementClass> class0ryzedFunction;



    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final HashMap<String, Function<? extends GenericContainer<?>, ? extends GenericContainer<?>>> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("My PRECIOUSSSS1", new MyReplacementClass2());
        map.put("My PRECIOUSSSS1", new MyReplacementInterface() {
            @Override public MyReplacementClass apply(final MyReplacementClass pT) {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

}
```